# using node and stripes api, how to first check the user's payment method for sufficient funds before charging them?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am using node and stripe. I need to a achieve a two step process.

1. Check that the user's payment method has sufficient funds for a specific amount.
2. If they do, then charge them that amount.

Else, error.

Answer (score 0):

There's [not really a way to do this with credit cards](https://support.stripe.com/questions/check-if-a-card-is-valid-without-a-charge#:%7E:text=it%20cannot%20check%20credit%20limits%20or%20account%20balances%20to%20guarantee%20that%20a%20card%20will%20have%20sufficient%20funds%20when%20you%20do%20decide%20to%20charge%20it). However, if you are using something like ACH Debit as a payment method, you could use [Financial Connections](https://stripe.com/en-gb-us/financial-connections) to check the account balance for sufficient funds prior to debiting the account.